# How to differentiate between null and empty string in pltcl?

Tags: postgresql, tcl

```
            set iNull 0
            set field_value [lindex [array get NEW $myfield] 1]
            if { [string length $field_value] == 0 } {
                set iNull 1
            }
```

I have written the trigger which runs this method of pltcl8.5(postgres) , here I want to check for null value and empty space.
I can't differentiate between both.
Note : There are no arguments passed to this method.

Answer (score 2):

[The pltcl manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pltcl-functions.html) covers this. Note in particular:

> To detect whether a particular argument is null, use the function `argisnull`.

Comment: I don't have arguements , I have values.

Comment: @user2181531 Then there is no difference, because tcl doesn't have a null or undefined value. In any case, if it's not a pltcl argument or return value this is just a question about the tcl language, not pltcl. You can unset variables, that's about it. http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Undefined_values#Tcl